# Adding a facebook like button to a website

Tags: facebook

I want to add a like button to my website but I'm having trouble doing so.
After some research I found this code that has to be right after the opening body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and with it comes this code that goes where I want my like button in the page:

```
<div class="fb-like"
  data-href="http://www.facebook.com/curlybracketssarl"
  data-width="200" data-layout="standard" data-action="like"
  data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Yet nothing is showing, I even tried to do so in a blank page and got no results once again.

So can you kindly tell me how to do what I need to do?

Comment: Are you getting  errors in the console?

Comment: Are you viewing your test page via HTTP/HTTPS  - or just via the local file system?

Comment: I a question for you just before I answer your question. Are you looking forward towards a fake like button that will only show the user a notif to the user that he has liked OR are you looking for a real like button that actually will keep track of the amount of likes that you have received. Please reply to my question if you expect a solution :)

Comment: no errors, just a blank page

Comment: @JohanGodinho I'm looking for a real like button

Comment: "I" is always UPPERCASE in English. [Other nice tips.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163)